# Evaluate the integral using the given data

Tags: integration

> Let $f:[0,1]\to [0,1]$ be a continuous function such that $x^2 +(f(x))^2\le 1$ for all $x\in [0,1]$ and $\int_0^1 f(x).dx=\frac{\pi}{4}$, then find $\int_{-1/2}^{1/\sqrt 2} \frac{f(x)}{1-x^2}.dx$

The part that’s throwing me off the inequality function. I have no idea how to solve such that problems. Can I get a hint?

Answer (score 2):

It is a badly written question. It says for all $x \in (0,1)$ and does not define $f(x)$ for $x \lt 0$ and then asks to integrate for negative values of $x$. Anyway I assume the given equation is true for all $x \in (-1, 1)$.

$x^2 + (f(x))^2 \leq 1$ for all $x \ $ and $\displaystyle \int_0^1 f(x) \ dx = \frac{\pi}{4}$.

And we need to find $\displaystyle \int_{-1/2}^{1/ \sqrt2} \frac{f(x)}{1-x^2} \ dx$

We know from the equation that $x^2 + (f(x))^2 \leq 1$ is a circle. The inequality ensures that you cover all the points inside the circle, in addition to covering points on the circle because the question is about area.

The next point which show the integral $I = \frac{\pi}{4} \ $ for $0 \leq x \leq 1$ only reiterates that the function is never negative otherwise the area would be $\frac{\pi}{2}$ for $0 \leq x \leq 1$.

So the integral that we need to find simply translates to $\displaystyle \int_{-1/2}^{1/ \sqrt2} \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}} \ dx$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint :**

$$f(x) \leq \sqrt{1-x^2}$$

It means graph of $f(x)$ always lies on or below the unit circle in the first quadrant.

Now what can you conclude from following? $$\int_{0}^{1} f(x) \, dx = \frac{\pi}{4}$$

Think area!

Comment: @AlbusDumbledore good luck for your exam! By the way I did not understand your comment about integrating both sides of the inequality.

Comment: @MathLover oh that integrating we get $\int_0^1 f(x)\le \pi/4$ which means the equalty must occur

Comment: @AlbusDumbledore Integrating we get $\frac{\pi}{4}$ which is area. There is no inequality here. It is a very standard practice to represent a closed curve with inequality when it is about area otherwise we remain on the curve. Similarly for volume in a closed surface otherwise remain on the surface. If you read $f(x) = y$ in the question, it becomes more clear, may be.

Comment: @MathLover i integrated both sides of inequality $f(x)\le \sqrt{1-x^2}$ which gave $\int_0^1f(x)\le \pi/4$ but as $\int_0^1 f(x)=\pi/4$ this means $f(x)=\sqrt{1-x^2}$ for all $x $ in domain

Comment: That is not true. Take $x = 0.1, f(x) = 0.1$. Is this point in the domain or not? Also not clear what is both sides of inequality.

Comment: @MathLover if a function (differntiable) $f(x)\le g(x)$ for all x doesnt that mean $\int_a^b f(x)\le \int_a^b g(x)$

Comment: That is not at all the point that I am making. I am not sure how you infer that from my previous comment. I am asking how you plan to cover all points inside the circle if $x^2 + y^2 = 1$ instead of $\leq 1$? Anyway we can continue in chat some other time or now whatever you prefer. I don't want to distract you. Again good luck for your exam.

Comment: Are we supposed to find $f(x)$ from the integral?

Comment: @Aditya yes you can deduce from the integral that $f(x) =\sqrt{1-x^2}$ but only over [0, 1]. As MathLover points, the problem then shouldn't be asking for integral over negative bounds as function is not defined there. You'll probably have to assume function is defined the same over negative interval also.

Comment: How is $f(x)=\sqrt{1-x^2}$? My problem is that I don’t find the integral useful in finding the function. Can you just decide upon just because the areas match?

Comment: @Aditya, it's not only area, the domain and range are also same. Then the inequality $\int f dx \le \int \sqrt{1-x^2}\,  dx$  states, $f(x)$ can either have smaller or equal area with $\sqrt{1-x^2}$ over $[0,1]$. Equality will occur if and only if at every $x$, the height $f(x)$ of  rectangles matches the height $\sqrt{1-x^2}$ of rectangles of Riemann sum.